# Android SQLite Delete row issue

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to delete a row from a table but i have three WHERE clauses and i am not sure if i am using the correct statement.

```
    db.delete(DBAdapter.TableName, "Id="+ Id
          +" AND WHERE QstnrId = "+Integer.parseInt(QuestionnaireId)
          +" AND WHERE QstnId = "+Integer.parseInt(QuestionId), null);
```

I am almost certain i am not using the statement correctly. Please assist?

Comment: is your tablename correct? Is your Id field unique? (if so, why the extra QstnrId and QstnId?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need to use the `WHERE` keyword. Also you could try using the third parameter to `delete()`:

```
db.delete(DBAdapter.TableName, "Id=? AND QstnrId=? AND QstnId=?",
          new String[] { Id.toString(), QuestionnaireId, QuestionId });
```

Comment: sorry yeh i think that works, i am not passing down the correct values into the id fields