# How to delete specific record from SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need to delete the specific record from **sqlite**. But following code not able to delete it.
Please give me some hint.

```
public void delete(String Id)
{
    try {

        db.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, "Id=?",
              new String[] { Id.toString() });
    }
    catch(Exception e) { ... }

}
```

Comment: Try looking intot he database and see if you are doing it correctly. And by correctly, I mean mapping it to the correct table name/column/value.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/delete-row-in-sqlite-database.html                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850137/android-sqlite-delete-row-issue

Comment: Have you tried not swallowing the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this:

```
public void delete(String Id)
{
    try {

        db.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, "Id="+Id, null);
    }
    catch(Exception e) { ... }
}
```

Comment: No any error. but i don't know exact problem.here is my updated... public void delete(int value)
 {
     try{

      db.execSQL("delete from TABLE_NAME where COLUMN_ID="+value);
 
 }
     catch(Exception e){}

 }

Comment: try to remove `try` and `catch`

Comment: finally i got. SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
      db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID+"="+value, null);... Thank you very much Natali!

Answer (score 5):

*(UPDATED)* You should use:

```
db.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, "Id=?", new String[] { Id });
```

And actually it's **suggested** to use not 'Id', but `BaseColumns._ID`, which is equal "_id".

**EDIT**: For the future users.

What is the difference between the following methods:

```
1. db.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, "_id=" + Id, null);
2. db.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[] {Id});
3. db.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, TABLE.ID_COLUMN_NAME + "=?", new String[] {Id});
```

I can say that all they work well. The difference between the first and the second method is that in general the second method is quicker than first and safer. Why quicker? Because Android can make a cache of parametrized queries, this parametrized query will be faster after the first time. Android cannot make a cache of the first query. Why safer? It's free of SQL injection.

The difference between the second and the third method is that the id column name is not hardcoded in all queries. You can simply define this field only once and then if the name of the column is changed you need to change it only in one place.

Comment: I use mDb.delete("TABLE_NAME", TABLE.ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(rowId)}); and it's working. If it's not working then maybe error in other place.

Comment: Sorry, in your case parameter is a string, so you should use:
db.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, "Id=?",
          new String[] { Id });

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    myDB = myDbHelper.openDataBase();
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    throw sqle;
}
String strFilter = "ID =" + ID;
myDB.delete("Table1, strFilter, null);
myDB.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can execute a simple DELETE SQL Query like :

```
"DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id = ?"
```

and pass the id value as a parameter to that query ...

Answer (score 1):

Use this
     where

```
  ourDatabase ="your database name"
  KEY_ROWID="rowid" of your database
&  int l=rowid number of which data you want to delete
   ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID+"="+l, null);
```

if you put null instead of KEY_ROWID+"="+l than it delete all data

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to delete the Record in Database

```
public void deleteRowFromTable(String tableName, String columnName, String keyValue) {
mSQLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();//To delete , database should be writable.
    String mColumName= columnName + "=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(keyValue)};
    mSQLiteDatabase.delete(tableName, mColumName, whereArgs);
mSQLiteDatabase.close();//This is very important once database operation is done.

}
```